# MySQL JOIN TABLES display with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a challenge trying to merge output using PHP from two TABLES in a MySQL database. I am not sure how to put the SELECT string to get certain columns from both of the TABLES I want to pull data from.

In one TABLE I have a unique identifier (bid) and this identifier is also present in the second TABLE.

The first TABLE represents a ticket buyer (table name = eventoslotickerbuyer). And the second TABLE represents guests (table name = eventosloguests).
The structure of the **eventosloticketbuyer** TABLE looks like this:

```
bid
firstname
lastname
email
cellphone
privatekey
eventid
orderdatetime
confirmeddatetime
```

The **eventosloguests** TABLE has the following structure:

```
gid
gfirstname
glastname
gemail
bid
eventid
registered
confirmed
confcode
```

What I want to accomplish, is to pull **firstname** and **lastname** from the "first" table, then pull **gfirstname** and **glastname** from the "second" table. The column that exists in both tables are the **bid**.

I can't figure out how the query should look like, so would appreciate some help.

Sincerely,
 Andreas

**UPDATE:**

I got it to work buy writing the query like this:

```
SELECT a.firstname, a.lastname, b.gfirstname, b.glastname
FROM eventosloticketbuyer a
INNER JOIN eventosloguests b ON a.bid = b.bid
```

What I still do not know is, if there is no GUEST connected to a BUYER, would this end up in blanks or should I switch it in some way to secure that I fetch the BUYER by using the GUEST as source?

Comment: pls post the tables structure

Comment: @Stephan Could you please guide me that best way to do that? I am not that very skilled.

Comment: i saw that u already did that ... the answer from `fthiella` wasn't what you needed?

Comment: I am about to give it a go right now. Will keep you posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to JOIN your tables, using for example an INNER JOIN that will select all record from both tables that have the same `bid`:

```
SELECT buyers.firstname, buyers.lastname, guests.gfirstname, guests.lastname
FROM
  buyers INNER JOIN guests
  ON buyers.bid = guests.bid
```

you can also write the above query using aliases, to make it shorter to write:

```
SELECT b.firstname, b.lastname, g.gfirstname, g.lastname
FROM
  buyers b INNER JOIN guests g
  ON b.bid = guests.bid
```

b is just an alias for buyers, g is an alias for guests. Using an INNER JOIN you can return all rows from the buyers table that have a record that matches a row in the guests tables. If there are more rows that match, an INNER JOIN will perform a multiplication of all of those rows.

If there are some buyers with an bid but no guests with that bid, then they won't be returned. But you can use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT b.firstname, b.lastname, g.gfirstname, g.lastname
FROM
  buyers b LEFT JOIN guests g
  ON b.bid = guests.bid
```

that will return all buyers, and all guests that match. If there's no match, all values of guests table will be NULL. You can also have a RIGHT JOIN that return all rows from guests and only the buyers that matches (or you can just swap the order of buyers and guests).

You can have a look at a [visual explanation of SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) to learn more about joins.

Comment: Thank you taking your time and effort to provide an answer. Unfortunately I am not smart enough to figure out how I shall do the replacements. I updated my post so that perhaps you could use the actual table names. What confuses me are the **buyers b** and **guests g**. I am not sure what those actually represents. :)

Comment: @Andreas i updated my answer, please let me know if everything is clear :)

Comment: **Thank you very much for this explanation!** I am starting to grip it now I think. :) And thank you very much for the link to the visual explanation of SQL joins. By reading your reply, I think what I want to achieve is a **LEFT JOIN** where I swap between buyers and guests, so that I get all guests and their matching buyers. :) Again, thank you!